# In MS C# Unit Testing, how to Assert that an ArgumentException occured?

Tags: unit-testing, exception

If we do a

```
throw new ArgumentException("Cannot do that");
```

How do you Assert that this `ArgumentException` happened with Microsoft's Testing Framework?

Comment: Possible Duplicate [C#: How do I use Assert (Unit Testing) to verify that an exception has been thrown?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/933613/299327).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could decorate your unit test with the [`[ExpectedException]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute(VS.80).aspx) attribute:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestMethod]
public void Foo()
{
    throw new ArgumentException("foo");
}
```

Don't ask though about asserting the exception message :-)

Comment: Thus why Unit tests shouldn't test more than one thing.  What if you did a Try / Catch then processed the caught exception with an Assert?

Comment: Well, of course you could do that but in this case you will be writing, let me count, 7 more lines of code (probably a bit less if you put the `{` on the same line), and every line of code you write is hiding a potential error and decreasing the readability of the code, so why doing it when you can avoid it :-)