# Explicitly setting a test to pass/fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

In the test below, if it enters the catch block I want to indicate that the test has passed. If the catch block is bypassed I want the test to fail.

Is there a way to do this, or am I missing the point with how tests should be structured?

```
[TestMethod]
public void CommandExecutionWillThrowExceptionIfUserDoesNotHaveEnoughEminence()
{
    IUserCommand cmd = CreateDummyCommand("TEST", 10, 10);
    IUser user = new User("chris", 40);

    try
    {
        cmd.Execute(user);
    }
    catch(UserCannotExecuteCommandException e)
    {
        //Test Passed
    }

    // Test Failed
}
```

Comment: `CommandExecutionWillThrowExceptionIfUserDoesNotHaveEnoughEminence`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933613/c-how-do-i-use-assert-unit-testing-to-verify-that-an-exception-has-been-thro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the test to throw UserCannotExecuteCommandException, when that happens the test will succeed

```
[ExpectedException( typeof( UserCannotExecuteCommandException) )]
```

Comment: But does the test also succeed if the exception is *not* thrown? The OP needs the test to fail if no exception is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for this. How do I prevent Visual Studio from stopping the execution of the tests when the actual exception is thrown? For example, I have to press F5/Continue before the test continues and can be marked as passed.

Comment: @Chris: Run the test *without* debugging (CTRL R, T)

Answer (score 11):

I tend to use this pattern when I have a similar situation:

```
// ...
catch (UserCannotExecuteCommandException e)
{
    return;    // Test Passed
}

Assert.Fail();    // Test Failed -- expected exception not thrown
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Assert.Throws()](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=assertThrows&r=2.5) method:

```
Assert.Throws<UserCannotExecuteCommandException>() => cmd.Execute(user));
```

Id does all what you need. It expect that an exception of type `UserCannotExecuteCommandException` would be thrown whilst execution of the `cmd.Execute()` method, otherwise automatially marks a test as failed.

Answer (score 0):

Since `[ExpectedException(...)]` is concidered as a bad practice you might use:

- MSTest: `Assert.ThrowsException<UserCannotExecuteCommandException >( () => cmd.Execute(user) );`
- NUnit: `Assert.Throws<UserCannotExecuteCommandException >( () => cmd.Execute(user) );`

then you are able to point which line exactly should throw an exception.