# Prevent VS C# Unit Testing breaking on exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I want to write a unit test for detecting a thrown exception. Using [`ExpectedExceptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx), I run the test from inside MSVS and when the TestMethod hits the exception, the debugger breaks to the exception but the TestMethod correctly skips over and reports Passed.

Is there a flag to tell VS not to break during unit testing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not run the tests in a debug session. You have the option to 'Run Selection' or 'Debug selection', choose the first and you should be fine.

Comment: @Jake Use ctrl + F5 in this scenario, which is the same as running the selection (non debug)

Comment: Yes, I realised my CTRL was not working! So I deleted my previous comment. After reading your answer, I found the "Test" menu so I thought I had to run from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you press `CTRL + ALT + E` you can configure whether the debugger will break when different types of exceptions are thrown and/or not handled.

I have found using these settings to be very handy at times.

Comment: There are lots of options (checkboxes) on that dialog (Debug:Exceptions).  I have found that I only need to uncheck the Common Language Runtime Exceptions (line) Thrown (column) box.  I agree that another option is to run without the debugger, but sometimes you do want to run with the debugger for some reason.  So, this is a good option when you need to use the debugger and don't want to break on first chance exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the MS Unit specific `[ExpectedException]`, if you need to debug your unit tests, you can explicitly try/catch the exception and Assert the type of exception, such as done here: [How do I use Assert to verify that an exception has been thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933613/c-how-do-i-use-assert-unit-testing-to-verify-that-an-exception-has-been-thro#933623)