# C# How I can expect a exception in Assert.AreEqual?

Tags: c#, exception, assert

**Example:**

```
Assert.AreEqual(**null**, Program.nDaysMonth(5, -10), "Error nDaysMonth, Month may -10.");
```

I expect a exception. How I can expect a exception in Assert.AreEqual?

Thanks.

Comment: If you expect an exception, why use `Assert`? Why not decorate your method with `ExpectedException`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933613/how-do-i-use-assert-to-verify-that-an-exception-has-been-thrown - if that doesn't fulfil your needs add extra info on why not.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a unit test to verify that `Program.nDaysMonth(5, -10)` throws an exception?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you shouldnt use ExpectedException attribute, its not nice. Instead of this use Assert.Throws method. Then you know exactly where the exception occurred and the test is written better.

Comment: Please specify the unit test framework you're using - we can't tell that just from your code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't use `Assert.AreEqual`, you use `Assert.Throws`:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => Program.nDaysMonth(5, -10));
```

This checks that the correct exception is thrown. If you want to add more assertions, you can use the return value:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(...);
Assert.AreEqual("Foo", exception.Message); // Or whatever
```

This works in at least NUnit and xUnit; if you're using a different testing framework you should look for similar functionality. If it doesn't exist, I'd recommend implementing it yourself - it's easy enough to do, and much cleaner than the alternatives (a try/catch block, or a method-wide `ExpectedException` attribute). Alternatively, change unit test framework if you can...

I'd also *strongly* advise you to start following the normal .NET naming conventions - `nDaysMonth` is *not* a good method name...

Some frameworks support decorating the method with an `[ExpectedException]` attribute - I would recommend *against* using that:

1. That makes the test unclear about where you expect the exception to be thrown.
2. If the exception is thrown elsewhere in the test method (i.e. your code is broken) the test will still pass.
3. You can't do anything else after the exception is thrown.
4. You can't check anything else about the exception.

Comment: [`Assert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx) doesn't have a method called `Throws`. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @oleksii: 1) That makes the test unclear about where you expect the exception to be thrown. 2) If the exception is thrown elsewhere in the test method (i.e. your code is broken) the test will still pass. 3) You can't do anything else after the exception is thrown. 4) You can't check anything else about the exception. Basically, it's a bad idea.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: There's no single `Assert` class for unit testing - there's the one in NUnit, the one in xUnit, the one in Microsoft Test, etc.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I have been explicit about that in the answer.

Comment: @oleksii: I think it's generally a good idea to *suggest* that sort of change in a comment rather than making it yourself - in this case it conflicted with one of my own edits. Fixed it all up now though.

Comment: Thanks. I did it with [ExpectedException]. Sorry for the method name, Im Spanish and did bad the translate.

Comment: @Jesús: Did you read my reasons why using `ExpectedException` is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Microsoft test framework, you would need to decorate the method with the [ExpectedExceptionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx):

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //Do whatever causes the exception here
    }
}
```

The test will then pass or fail depending on the exception being thrown or not.

However, as Jon notes below, please find a test framework that supports `Assert.Throws` or some variation there-of. Decorating with the expected exception can cause false passes or other issues in code depending on what you are doing, and it makes it difficult to do anything after the exception is thrown in the method. Using a full-featured framework will improve the quality of your tests dramatically.

I recommend NUnit, http://www.nunit.org/

Or there are others like XUnit https://github.com/xunit/xunit

or literally dozens of others: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#.NET_programming_languages

Comment: That's a bad idea (IMO) for the reasons listed in a comment in my answer. Limiting the scope of the expected exception to a lambda expression is *much* cleaner IMO.

Comment: I agree, however without rolling your own and just using what is available (for quick tests) with MS, its about the only option. Its important if its used that it be the *only* test being done in the method for clarity in my opinion.

Comment: It's hardly the case that you *need* to decorate the method with the attribute then, is it? That's just if you can't be bothered to reimplement `Assert.Throws` - which is pretty simple, and makes all the rest of your tests clearer, IMO. I would definitely recommend doing that (or switching to a test framework that isn't stuck in the past...)

Comment: Thanks. I did it with [ExpectedException].