# unit test on exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm writing a unit test, where by I pass in a model and the title field in particular is required.

My test is as follows:

```
  [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception), "Movie Title is mandatory")]
    public void Create()
    {
        var mc = new MoviesController();

        var model = new Movie
        {
            Cast = new[] { "Scott", "Joe", "mark" },
            Classification = "PG",
            Genre = null,
            MovieId = 0,
            Rating = 5,
            ReleaseDate = 2004,
            Title = null
        };

        var rep = mc.Create(model);
    }
```

Which calls this class via the controller:

```
public int Create(Movie movie)
    {
        int num;
        if (MovieRepository.Movies == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Movies datasource is not available");
        }
        lock (MovieRepository._dsMovies)
        {
            DataRow str = MovieRepository._dsMovies.Tables["Movie"].NewRow();
            int num1 = MovieRepository._pk + 1;
            MovieRepository._pk = num1;
            int num2 = num1;
            movie.MovieId = num2;
            str["Id"] = num2;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Title))
            {
                throw new Exception("Movie Title is mandatory");
            }
            str["Title"] = movie.Title.Trim();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Genre))
            {
                str["Genre"] = movie.Genre.Trim();
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Classification))
            {
                str["Classification"] = movie.Classification.ToString();
            }
            str["Rating"] = movie.Rating;
            str["ReleaseDate"] = movie.ReleaseDate;
            MovieRepository._dsMovies.Tables["Movie"].Rows.Add(str);
            if ((movie.Cast == null ? 0 : (int)((int)movie.Cast.Length > 0)) != 0)
            {
                this.AddCast(movie);
            }
            MovieRepository._dsMovies.AcceptChanges();
            num = num2;
        }
        return num;
    }
```

As you can see it checks for the title

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movie.Title))
        {
            throw new Exception("Movie Title is mandatory");
        }
```

Can I assert that exception? because as it stands after it fails I click on the output to check the fail log and I see this :

> Test Name:              CreateMovie
>
> Test Outcome:       Failed
>
> Result Message:    Test method Project.Test.UnitTest1.CreateMovie did
>   not throw an exception. An exception was expected by attribute
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExpectedExceptionAttribute
>   defined on the test method.
>
> Result StandardOutput:
>
> System.Exception: Movie Title is mandatory
>
> at Movies.MovieRepository.Create(Movie movie)
>
> at Project.Web.Controllers.MoviesController.Create(Movie movie) in
>   c:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Project.Web\Project.Web\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:line
>   113

According to the result message it says it didn't throw an exception, when I know it did / should

Comment: Did you step through the code? What did the code actually do? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes I've stepped through the code when creating a new movie from the UI and it throws an exception "Movie title is mandatory"

Comment: I didn't ask whether you stepped through the code when calling from the UI. The relevant scenario is whether you stepped through the code during the unit test. Did you actually _debug the unit test_? If so, what did you find?

Comment: @PeterDuniho apologies, yes I have debugged it, and it does throw the exception Movie Title is mandatory, I have just wrapper a try catch statement around the unit test and again the exception is caught

Comment: Note that `ExpectedException` will happily report success if test fails for any other reasons (like errors in "arrange" part)... Consider other approaches shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933613/how-do-i-use-assert-to-verify-that-an-exception-has-been-thrown to capture particular exception at particular time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your unit test in a try catch, and put a debug point in the catch, so you can see it happening, and easily debug it:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception), "Movie Title is mandatory")]
public void Create()
{
    var mc = new MoviesController();

    var model = new Movie
    {
        Cast = new[] { "Scott", "Joe", "mark" },
        Classification = "PG",
        Genre = null,
        MovieId = 0,
        Rating = 5,
        ReleaseDate = 2004,
        Title = null
    };

    try
    {
        var rep = mc.Create(model);
        Assert.Fail("This shouldn't be shown, because the above should have thrown an exception ! !");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("AH ha! caught it ! :) : " + e);
        throw;
    }        
}
```

As an extra bonus, you can `Assert.Fail` so it won't get past it if it doesn't throw the exception.

As an even added bonus, you shouldn't be throwing an `Exception` but rather your own exception? maybe `MovieException`, so then you can catch specifically that exception.

Comment: No worries, hope it helped. Test on brother (or sister...) , and keep warm, Melbourne must be freezing ATM ...

Comment: Yes it's very cold at the moment ha ha, bring back the summer! quick question say I just wanted to assert a message for example "Hello World" when the test is run is that possible? if so how? because I can't seem to find any docs online

Comment: what do you mean ? on the exception?! or just on object, or a return value?

Comment: No just in general, so I wanted to create a new unit test, and inside that unit test it would just assert "Hello world" when I run all test, it has no object or return value it just simply asserts "Hello World" and the test passes

Comment: assert is a class that then asserts something: is true, is false, is same, is not, etc ... asserting "hello world" doesn't make sense to me ... you could `Assert.IsTrue(true,"good")`, but again, it's rather futile, isn't it ?

Comment: correct it is, but I was more curious if anything to see if it could be done, because your right it had no meaning what so ever.  I haven't done much with unit test, as the companies I have worked at normally have them all in place with the odd exception etc. Thanks again

Comment: Then go and have a read : [unit test introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784791/Introduction-to-Unit-Testing-with-MS-tests-NUnit-a). Wrote it as an intro, but you can probably pick something interesting and/or useful :)