# Unity unit tests - Check if the function call with an argument throws an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, exception

I unity I have a function to call with wrong arguments and I want to make sure that the function throw the right exception with the right message. So my function call is this:

```
winDetector.DoMove(move)
```

And it should throw and exception like this:

```
throw new Exception("Move is not valid.");
```

Looks like I should use `Assert.Throws<Exception>` but I don't know how. Now to both Unity and C#. How can I do this?

P.S. `Assert.Throws<Exception>` is not the correct way. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Assert to verify that an exception has been thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933613/how-do-i-use-assert-to-verify-that-an-exception-has-been-thrown)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. See the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an elegant way to do that. Here is how it should be done:

```
Assert.That(() => winDetector.DoMove(move), 
                  Throws.TypeOf<Exception>());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Assert.Throws<Exception>` is the right way to do this:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>( () => winDetector.DoMove(move) );
```

The `() =>` part is necessary because the `Assert.Throw<>()` method will takes a TestDelegate which can be a lambda function but not an arbitrary unwrapped function.

`Assert.Throws<>()` should be preferred to `Assert.That<>()` because it more succinctly and specifically species what is being asserted.

---

Note: this method does not appear in Unity's [documentation for the Assert class](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Assertions.Assert.html), however Unity appears to be using an NUnit derived Assert class documented [here](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/assertions/classic-assertions/Assert.Throws.html). Because this is undocumented it may not be stable in future versions.