# Check if exception thrown (and correct exception) with Microsoft testing tools

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, exception, epplus

Consider a method which returns an `ExcelWorksheet` from an `ExcelPackage` (with the Epplus library):

```
public ExcelWorksheet findExcelSheet(ExcelPackage spreadsheet, string v)
```

This method throws an `Exception` if a worksheet is not found within the spreadsheet whose name is "v".

A unit test is written for this method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void findExcelSheet_Test()
{
    // arrange
    ExcelPackage testSpreadsheet = new ExcelPackage();
    ExcelWorksheet testWsFPS = testSpreadsheet.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("FPS");
    ExcelWorksheet testWsDRS = testSpreadsheet.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DRS");
    ExcelWorksheet testWsDPC = testSpreadsheet.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DPC");

    // act
    findExcelSheet(testSpreadsheet, Path.GetRandomFileName()); //or some other random string

    // assert
}
```

How, with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`, can it be tested for when it throws the exceptions, and that they are the correct type of exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Assert to verify that an exception has been thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933613/how-do-i-use-assert-to-verify-that-an-exception-has-been-thrown)

Comment: @Clint I will check if it works tomorrow, but it looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [MSTest V2] to be able to Assert.ThrowsException

Starting with VS2017, the in-box Unit Test Project templates use only MSTest V2.

- Install package `MSTest.TestFramework` from Nuget
- Install package `MSTest.TestAdapter` from Nuget
- Then you can use `Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>..`

```
 //Substitute `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with the exception that you receive
 Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>( ()=>FindExcelSheet(spreadsheet,""));
```