# XUnit Asserting Exceptions In Debug Mode In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit

Am I correct in thinking that you can't run this code:

```
Assert.Throws<FormatException>(()=> 
{
     int test;
     test = int.Parse("forty two");

});
```

in debug mode? It will throw an error and that error will not be caught by the

```
Assert.Throws<FormatException>
```

So the test will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to this, [How to prevent expected exceptions from breaking the debug test run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362239/how-to-prevent-expected-exceptions-from-breaking-the-debug-test-run)

Probably is your Visual Studio settings that are wrong, not xunit