# Is there any easier way to test release steps then this cycle

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am testing SQL scripts deployment automation using VSTS, the cycle I am following to test if my release cycle is working for different scenarios is as follow,

- Make changes to SQL Project in VS, build and push to VSTS repo
- Make changes to release steps for deploy dacpac if required
- Create a new release
- Deploy and repeat for redeploy

I have to test lots of scenarios including but not limited to followings,

- Add a new table to sql project and test if it works
- Delete a column and rollback changes if something goes wrong
- Modify column and check if any data loss happens...
- etc..

Comment: What do you think of my suggestion? Regarding schema changes, it will throw exception if you want to retrieve the data from a non-existing table or column and the test will be fail (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741029/best-way-to-test-exceptions-with-assert-to-ensure-they-will-be-thrown). If I misunderstand, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to these steps:

1. Create database unit test project to do test with database: Walkthrough: [Creating and Running a SQL Server Unit Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212(v=vs.103).aspx)
2. Refer to this article to deploy Database: [Deploy your database to Azure SQL Database using DACPACs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/cd/deploy-dacpac-sqlpackage) (If you are not using azure DB, [using WinRM - SQL Server Database Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/d84c114051008f96c135d0d96fa1ecc63a3c6279/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/SqlDacpacDeploy/README.md) instead)
3. Add [Visual Studio Test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-continuous-testing) to run database unit test

Comment: This does not answer the question. The person was not asking about deploying database changes or how to test stored procedures; the question was about **testing deployment of schema changes**.