# Why do I need a different syntax when testing for an exception with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I have a test like this...

```
it("should calculate factorial 5", function() {
  expect(MathsUtils.fact(5)).toBe(120);
});
```

This works fine. My fact function throws an exception if you pass it a negative number, so I tried to test that with the following...

```
it("should throw an exception when passed -1", function() {
  expect(MathsUtils.fact(-1)).toThrow("n! does not exist for negative numbers");
});
```

However, this failed. After some searching, I discovered that if I change this test to look like this...

```
it("should throw an exception when passed -1", function() {
  expect(function() { MathsUtils.fact(-1); }).toThrow("n! does not exist for negative numbers");
});
```

...it passes. However, if I change my first test in a similar manner...

```
it("should calculate factorial 5", function() {
  expect(function() { MathsUtils.fact(5); }).toBe(120);
});
```

...it fails.

Why do I need a different syntax for the two tests? Neither seems to work for the other.

As I said, I'm new with Jasmine, so if this is covered in the docs, please point me in the right direction, as I couldn't see any explanation.

Comment: that's how it was implemented, you just have to use it like that. Have you tried `toThrowError`

Comment: Because, **per the documentation**, *"The 'toThrow' matcher is for testing if a function throws an exception"*. Otherwise the exception would be thrown *before* `expect` actually gets called.

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe I tried toThrowError, but that also failed. Do you have a link to the docs? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example

```
expect(MathsUtils.fact(-1))
```

The `fact` is evaluated **before** `expect` is called, and hence it cannot catch the exception,

where

```
expect(function(){MathsUtils.fact(-1)})
```

`expect` is doing the execution and can catch the exception as what is passed is a function pointer and not an already evaluated value

Comment: Ah, that's probably what @jonrsharpe meant. I was about to ask him to explain it. Do you have a link to the docs for this? I found them a bit hard to navigate. Thanks

Comment: No reference -- this is a JavaScript thing and not really related to Jasmine -- anything that is inside a function/closure is evaluated `later` by the receiver

Comment: OK, I guess this is where my lack of knowledge of the finer points of Javascript start to show. I'm a C# programmer by day, doing some web stuff as extras. Do you know where I'd find more info about this. I'd like to learn how this works. Thanks again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Thanks, plenty to read there! I thought I had a handle on closures, but it looks like there's a lot more to learn. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is an addendum to the comments in Soren's answer.

> `expect` is doing the execution and can catch the exception as what is passed is a function pointer and not an already evaluated value

Take a look under the hood of Jasmine 2.6:

When you [call the `expect()` method](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.6.0/src/core/Spec.js#L45) several things happen ...

1. [Create the `Expectation`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.6.0/src/core/Expectation.js#L87) which is [defined here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.6.0/src/core/Expectation.js#L7)
2. The "toThrow" matcher defines a `compare()` method which is [mixed into the `Expectation` object](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.6.0/src/core/Expectation.js#L76).

**tl;dr:**

3. In `toThrow()` the `actual` value, along with the `expected` value, was passed by the `compare()` call. The value is evaluated as function call [`within a try/catch block`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.6.0/src/core/matchers/toThrow.js#L26).

   ```
   function toThrow(util) {
     return {
       compare: function(actual, expected) {
         var result = { pass: false },
           threw = false,
           thrown;

         if (typeof actual != 'function') {
           throw new Error(getErrorMsg('Actual is not a Function'));
         }

         try {
           actual();
         } catch (e) {
           threw = true;
           thrown = e;
         }

         if (!threw) {
           result.message = 'Expected function to throw an exception.';
           return result;
         }

         // ...
       }
     }
   }
   ```

> Why do I need a different syntax for the two tests? Neither seems to work for the other.

After reading `toThrow()` this should be clearer.

While a primitive type like a number or a string passed to, say, the `toBe()` matcher can be evaluated immediately, the "value" of an exception (that are the `threw` and `thrown` variables up there) is created when thrown **and** when not thrown. Thus the macher should hold the control of the execution.

---

Note that

```
it("should throw", function() {
    expect(someFunction()).toThrow("meh");
});
```

will semi-work since `someFunction()` may throw and the suite will catch that exception and report a spec failure when the closure passed to `it()` is being executed.

But since in this case neither `expect()` nor `toThrow()` are called, it's not able to check for the message nor the type (like `toThrowError()` does). It's only able to detect that the spec failed.

---

This small example which can run in NodeJS or a browser console should make it even clearer ...

You can also make your own expectation function:

```
// Expectation constructor
function Expectation(actual, reporter) {
    this.actual = actual;
    this.reporter = reporter;
}

// matcher "mixed in"
Expectation.prototype.toThrow = function(expected) {
    try {
        this.actual();

        // No exception thrown, this state is wrong
        this.reporter(false, "Expected " + this.actual.name + " to throw but it did not throw");
    } catch(e) {
        // This exception was expected, this state is correct

        if (e.message !== expected) {
            // But the message was wrong

            this.reporter(false, "Expected " + this.actual.name + " to throw " + expected + " but it threw " + e.message);
        } else {
            // And its message was correct

            this.reporter(true);
        }
    }
};

// Helper to report (log)
function report(passed, msg) {
    if (!passed) {
        console.error(msg);
    } else {
        console.log("passed");
    }
} 

// Helper to create expectation
function expect(actual) {
    return new Expectation(actual, report);
}

> function correctError() { throw new Error("meh!"); }
> expect(correctError).toThrow("meh!");
< passed

> function badMessageError() { throw new Error("hehe"); }
> expect(badMessageError).toThrow("meh!");
< Expected badMessageError to throw meh! but it threw hehe

> function noError() { /* no action */ }
> expect(noError).toThrow("meh!");
< Expected noError to throw but it did not throw
```

---

Per your comment

> [...] I'm a C# programmer by day, [...]

there's [a nice C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742201/1078886) to a similar question that implements the same behaviour like Jasmine.